# best way to find extra object among two lists

Tags: java, performance, list, collections

I have two custom lists say CompanyList such that

```
public class CompanyList<E> extends Collection<E> implements List<E> {}
```

Here I have list of CompanyList such that

```
public class CompanyMakeVO extends BaseVO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public CompanyMakeVO() {
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // overrides equals
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj.getClass() == this.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        CompanyMakeVO make = (CompanyMakeVO) obj;

        // NAME
        String thisName = this.getName();
        String thatName = make.getName();

        if (null == thisName || null == thatName)
            return false;

        return thisName.equals(thatName);
    }

    // hashcode
    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    }
}
```

I have two such lists say oldList and newList both have some objects of CompanyMakeVO, each object represents a company name via name attribute.
Lets say Old list has 3 objects with name as Audi, BMW and Aston Martin while new list has 5 objects with name as Audi, BMW, Aston Martin, Jaquar and Tesla. The Lists will not have any duplicates items i.e comapny name will not be repeated. I need to find the unique element present in either list and also with the list name and element name. 
What's the best way to find it out?

Comment: `longerList.removeAll(shorterList)`.

Comment: hashCode is incorrectly implemented (can throw NullPointerException when name is not assigned). Fix the code first.

Comment: `newList.retainAll(oldList);` use this to compare both list

Comment: CommonsUtils is your friend (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html ) CommonsUtils.subtract(), CommonsUtils.intersection() and other ones.

Answer (score 2):

For small data sets, lists with a few elements, it is convenient to use `List.removeAll()`.
For large data sets, like lists with millions of items, you can use a `HashMap` to get those elements.
Since `List.removeAll()` will try to compare each item in the first list against all elements in the second list, which is O(NM) complexity. For using `HashMap`, it only needs O(N+M), faster than the first one.

Comment: Well, my list contains few elements but I prefer to go with HashSet. As it's not sure which contains more elements it can be in either of the lists. If I go with List.removeAll()  again I need to copy all the data into temporary lists and its looks like more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAll`() method from `ArrayList` as given below:

```
List<CompanyMakeVO> companyMakeVOListOld = new ArrayList<>();
//add your items to the old list

List<CompanyMakeVO> companyMakeVOListNew = new ArrayList<>();
//add your items to new list

//now removeAll duplicate items from new list by passing the old list
companyMakeVOListNew.removeAll(companyMakeVOListOld);
```

**ArrayList - removeAll method API:**

> public boolean removeAll(Collection c)
>
> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)